# Type Family returning (a -> Type)

Tags: haskell, type-families, type-level-computation

I have a class:

```
class C (g :: [a] -> Type) where
   type ExtractType g :: a -> Type
```

But I am not sure how to write the type family instance

```
instance C X where
   type ExtractType X = ???
```

`Type` is `*` from `GHC.Types`.
For example, lets say I have an named `NHList (ts::[(Symbol,Type)])`, then `ExtractType NHList` should return `(Symbol,Type) -> Type` and be equivalent to `Snd`.

Comment: `ExtractType X a = ...`?

Comment: Too many parameters to ExtractType:
        a is unexpected;

Comment: Well in that case I don’t know. Perhaps you could expand on an example of what `X` might be? And then what you would want `ExtractType X` to be? Does this class come from some package where you might be able to find a nontrivial instance?

Comment: What is `Type`? There are several definitions in common libraries, and of course there's no guarantee you haven't created it yourself, so at the moment the question isn't really complete.

Comment: Type is just `*`

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrast the two signatures:

```
type ExtractType g :: a -> Type
type ExtractType g (x :: a) :: Type
```

It may seem like merely a syntactic difference, but there's more to it than that.

Both definitions yield the same kind signature:

```
ghci> :kind ExtractType
ExtractType :: ([a] -> *) -> a -> *
```

So what's the difference?

The first definition declares that `ExtractType` is a type family (type function) that takes a single argument, and returns something of kind `a -> Type`.

The second one says that `ExtractType` is a type family of two arguments, returning something of kind `Type`. Using our intuition from the term-level, these two may sound equivalent, but that equivalence relies on partial application: the ability to pass around functions without fully saturating their arguments first. However, this is not allowed for type families: they must always be fully saturated.

More concretely, your example would look like

```
type family Snd (t :: (a, b)) :: b where
  Snd '(_, b) = b

...
instance C NHList where
  type ExtractType NHList = Snd
                            ^^^
```

Here, `Snd` is unsaturated, because it takes one argument, but it is given none.

The solution is simple: saturate `Snd`. To do this, we adopt the second version:

```
class C (g :: [a] -> Type) where
  type ExtractType g (x :: a) :: Type

instance C NHList where
  type ExtractType NHList a = Snd a
                              ^^^^^
```

#### Unsaturated type families

Now, I said that type families must always be fully saturated - but why is this? There are a few reasons, here's one of them.

The constraint solver used in GHC's type system makes the following assumption:

Given a known equality `f a ~ g b`, we can deduce that `f ~ g` and `a ~ b`.

```
fancyId :: f a ~ g b => a -> b
fancyId = id -- `a` must be the same as `b`
```

A type can be in the form `f a` when `f` is a type constructor, like `Maybe`, like `Maybe Int`. What if `f` could be a type family?

```
type family Dumb a b where
  Dumb _ b = b
```

With partial application, we could have something like `Dumb Int ~ Dumb String`, and GHC would readily derive `Int ~ String`. With the restriction that type families must be fully saturated, we can't even write down that equality, getting us away from the problem. Instead, `Dumb Int String ~ Dumb String a` now relates two fully saturated families, so they can first be reduced to `String ~ a`, and we're good.

#### Unsaturated type constructors

*Type constructors*, like `Maybe` or `Either` are allowed to be partially applied, however. That's because they have certain properties (namely generativity and injectivity) that allow us to deduce the equalities above.

Given `Either Int ~ Either a`, we can learn that `Int ~ a`, because `Either` is injective. `Snd` is not injective: `Snd '(Int, String) ~ Snd '(Char, String)` holds, but that doesn't mean `'(Int, String) ~ '(Char, String)`.

Summarising the above, the signature

```
type ExtractType g :: a -> Type
```

really means that `ExtractType` takes a single argument, and return a *type constructor*. A valid definition, albeit not a very useful one, would be

```
data Proxy (a :: k) = Proxy
...
type ExtractType g = Proxy
```

#### Type-lambdas

So what would happen if this restriction was lifted? As @pigworker mentioned, this would allow us to have type-level lambdas (well, not necessarily lambdas for us to use, but it would bring about the same problems as if we had lambdas):

Currently, if we know that for some `g` and `h`, `ExtractType g` and `ExtractType h` are the same, it must mean that they return the same type constructor, such as `Proxy` above (this is using the first definition). The equational theory here is pretty straightforward because we can easily decide when two type constructors are definitionally equal. Things get more complicated when `ExtractType g` is allowed to return any old type function: when are two type functions equal?

We could use definitional equality for the lambda terms, that is reducing them to their normal forms, and then using alpha-equivalence, but short of a strong normalisation property, this notion equality is undecidable. That's not necessarily a problem, but this is not something GHC does (yet).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
instance C X where
    type instance ExtractType X = Proxy
```

Given your update, I expect you will need to change the class to say `type ExtractType g (x :: a) :: Type` (and turn on `ScopedTypeVariables`). Then `type ExtractType X (sym, ty) = ty` should work fine.

Comment: Perhaps an explanation for why “type instance ExtractType X a = ...” fails is in order?

Comment: @HTNW It is a syntactic restriction; I expect this restriction is backed by a solid foundational motivation, but I've never looked into what it is.

Comment: @HTNW TO allow it would give us a type-level lambda by the back door.